# Spring StopWatch concurrency

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, stopwatch

I have a Bean configured as follow:

```
    @Bean(name = "myStopWatch")
    @Scope(value = "prototype")
    public MyStopWatch myStopWatch() {
       return new MyStopWatch();
    }
```

And MyStopWatch class is as follow:

```
import org.springframework.util.StopWatch;

public class MyStopWatch {

   private StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();

   public void start() {
       if(!sw.isRunning()) {
           sw.start();
       }
   }

   public void stop() {
       if(sw.isRunning()) {
           sw.stop();
       }
   }
}
```

We're using this bean in a highly concurrent environment. If my understanding is correct, MyStopWatch class should never be shared bewtween thread, right?

However, we sometimes (very rarely) get the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start StopWatch: it's already
>   running   at
>   org.springframework.util.StopWatch.start(StopWatch.java:127)  at
>   org.springframework.util.StopWatch.start(StopWatch.java:116)

So far we couldn't reproduce this behavior with our test. I'm looking for more information regarding how I should correctly define my *sw* variable (or ma bean) in order to avoid this error.

Comment: What steps are you undertaking to avoid sharing of `MyStopWatch` objects among the threads?

Comment: I thought that having the bean set with prototype scope should be enough.

Comment: There you are: the "effects" during production runs are most likely due to a race condition. There's no guarantee that there is no thread rescheduling between `sw.isRunning()` and `sw.start()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. Declaring a bean as `prototype` does not ensure thread safety. Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15747339/5771446) for more details.

As far as using Spring's `StopWatch` goes, [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html) states that it is not designed to be thread-safe and is also not meant to be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's not thread safe, documentation says so. Having your beans as `prototype` does not mean that there can't be multiple threads updating it concurrently, it just means that when you ask for such a bean - a new instance is returned all the time (when using `getBean` or `@Autowired` for example).

If you want to measure *elapsed time* (how much it took to do something), stay off the `StopWatch` from Spring. If you have guava it has a `StopWatch` too - use that (it's still not thread-safe), otherwise a simple `System.nanoTime` inside each portion of the code you want to profile would be enough too.

Comment: What would be the benefits of using guava's `StopWatch' if that is not thread-safe as well?

Comment: @Synch it's using `System.nanoTime` underneath

Comment: @Eugene Ok thanks, but still, as mentioned by Synch, I still don't see the benefit of using the stopwatch from Guava. This wouldn't avoid having to implement a threadsafe solution ourselves.

Comment: @hublo right, but you are also missing the point here with your `MyStopWatch`. why do you need to extends it? and why expose two methods that guava for example already has. simply put those statements inside the method itself `public void test(){ StopWatch st = st.createStarted() ... do your stuff .. log st.elapsedTime... }`

Comment: @Eugene I'm not really extending it, but wrapping it around within a class which is responsible to provide several metrics. The reason why is because we do have several services sharing the same code insfrastructure, and we want to centralize the collect of metrics. Therefore, actually my problem is more to make this stuff thread safe rather than switching to another library for which I'll have to actually solve the same problem as well. I mean, even if I use the Guava SW, i'll have to wrap it within my class, and will encoutner the same problematic.

Comment: @hublo so you want to measure *not* some method, but some *methods* together? to give you a view of what is going on across multiple calls?

Comment: @Eugene yep, this is a very good definition of what we're doing.

Comment: @hublo thats still somehow questionable, you could bind a stopwatch to a thread via threadlocal for example, but u would need to dispose that too after a cartain call.

Comment: @hublo just may be there is a "startig method" that you could do `System.nanoTime` of, that will in turn call all the methods u are interested in. Notice that it seems u dont want thread safety here but more per thread timing, it seems to me. Unless of course you do some async or rx or whatever that will dispatch your calls to some other thread, in which case this will not work