# Providing default values for validation in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, validation

I want SpringBoot to be able to provide default values for fields that the user must enter.  For example, I have something like this:

```
*Controller class*
@PostMapping("/test")
public ResponseEntity<> myMethod(@RequestBody @Valid MyContract contract) {}

*MyContract class*

@Valid
DataObject dataObject;

*DataObject class*

@Component
public class DataObject {
   private @Value("${field1.default}") String field1Default;
   private String field1

   public String getField1() {
     return (field1 == null ? field1Default : field1);
   }
}
```

The DataObject class needs to be created on a per request basis.  There are also other places in the code where it needs to be created on demand.  So I imagine it needs to be a Prototype object.  But I can't figure out how to get Spring to created it properly when it creates it for the request.

**Update**

I have read more about @RequstBody, e.g., https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring/spring-request-response-body/ and [Should spring @RequestBody class be singleton or prototype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67654969/should-spring-requestbody-class-be-singleton-or-prototype), which explains that the object is not a Component, but a simple POJO that gets the values from the Json request.  So it seems that there is no way to inject @Values from the Spring application.properties file.  Is there any other way around this?  Or another suggested implementation?

Comment: I assume that the request is a JSON object. So if the user doesn't enter anything it will be null or empty. The default value will not work. Either set the default value on the client or you have to get and set the default value in the myMethod or in getField1. The parameter cannot be  a Spring bean.

Comment: Thanks.  See my update.  I didn't realize that `MyContract` class cannot be a Bean.  I see that now.  Is there a suggested way of best implementing something like this?